# How to Pass data from PHP to PHP file

Tags: php

I have a File named 1.php and I have another file named index.php

I use

```
include('index.php');
```

for including index data. Is there a way i can pass data to index.php file?

Comment: All the global variables defined before `include` are also available in the included PHP code.

Comment: is index.php inside 1.php?

Comment: Are you trying to pass data from 1.php to index.php or the other way round?

Comment: If you want to send data from one page to another page I would recommend looking to POST variables in PHP

Comment: Yes index.php is in 1.php file @EbrahimMohammed

Comment: 1.php to index.php @LewaBammyStephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if index.php is inside 1.php , you can do that:

1.php:

```
<?php $variable = "hello"; 
      include('index.php');
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php 
echo $variable; //this will output hello.
?>
```